# debezium - schema registry issue

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Im using AWS schema registry for debezium.

In the debezium I mentioned the server name as `mysql-db01`. So debezium will create a topic with this server name to add some metadata about the server and schema changes.

When I deployed the connector, in the schema registry I got the schema like this.

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SchemaChangeKey",
  "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.mysql",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "databaseName",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.SchemaChangeKey"
}
```

Then immediately another version got created like this.

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SchemaChangeValue",
  "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.mysql",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Source",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "version",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "connector",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "ts_ms",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "snapshot",
            "type": [
              {
                "type": "string",
                "connect.version": 1,
                "connect.parameters": {
                  "allowed": "true,last,false"
                },
                "connect.default": "false",
                "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Enum"
              },
              "null"
            ],
            "default": "false"
          },
          {
            "name": "db",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "sequence",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "table",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "server_id",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "gtid",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "file",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "pos",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "row",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "thread",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "long"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "query",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ],
        "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "databaseName",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "schemaName",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "ddl",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "tableChanges",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Change",
          "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.schema",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "type",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "table",
              "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Table",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "defaultCharsetName",
                    "type": [
                      "null",
                      "string"
                    ],
                    "default": null
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "primaryKeyColumnNames",
                    "type": [
                      "null",
                      {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": "string"
                      }
                    ],
                    "default": null
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "columns",
                    "type": {
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "Column",
                        "fields": [
                          {
                            "name": "name",
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "jdbcType",
                            "type": "int"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "nativeType",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "int"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "typeName",
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "typeExpression",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "string"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "charsetName",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "string"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "length",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "int"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "scale",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "int"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "position",
                            "type": "int"
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "optional",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "boolean"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "autoIncremented",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "boolean"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          },
                          {
                            "name": "generated",
                            "type": [
                              "null",
                              "boolean"
                            ],
                            "default": null
                          }
                        ],
                        "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.schema.Column"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.schema.Table"
              }
            }
          ],
          "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.schema.Change"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.SchemaChangeValue"
```

These 2 schemas are not matching, so the AWS schema registry is not allowing the connector to register the 2nd version. But the 2nd version is the actual schema for the connector.

To solve this issue, I deleted the schema(in the schema registry). Then deleted the connector, re-deployed the connector, then It worked.

But I'm trying to understand why the very first time the schema has different versions.

Comment: One schema is a key. The other is a value. Those should not be part of the same registry "subject"... You could fix this by not using the AvroConverter for the Kafka `key.converter`

Comment: Huh got it. So if I use Json convertor, will it fix this issue?

Comment: Assuming the AWS Schema Registry doesn't store JSON schemas like the Confluent one, then sure

Comment: It supports avro, Json and protopuf

Comment: Is there any way to solve this from connector side like not push this topic to the schema registry

Comment: Like I said, don't use a `key.converter` that intergrates with the registry, such as the built-in Kafka StringConverter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235557/discussion-between-bhuvanesh-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following key/value convertors on the source and sink connectors to make it work.

```
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.key.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.region": "ap-south-1",
        "key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": "true",
        "value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": "true",
        "key.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "value.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "key.converter.registry.name": "bhuvi-debezium",
        "value.converter.registry.name": "bhuvi-debezium",
```

Comment: why do you ever need to set `internal.key.*`/`internal.value.*`? they got deprecated since kafka v.2.0.0